# Preserve Photoshop PNG transparent margin from generator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, creative-cloud, android

[image: how i want drawer icon to look with margin]
[image: icon when generated]

I am trying to create a new color for a drawer icon in AS. The stock one has margin to the right that I would like to preserve since it keeps the actionbar icon from sitting on top of it. When I create a new drawer icon in PS and then generate the .png all the transparency is excluded. I think I'm failing to understand something simple here. I know default is 32bit png, just in case I generated the image using .png32 to force it with no difference in the final image. I tried making a transparent box and creating a smart object from it hoping that layer would be preserved but that didn't work either.

Comment: what application are you using to try to preserve the transparency?

Comment: I'm working in photoshop cc

Comment: Adding .png32 makes all my chosen layers to be transparent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The transparency is not excluded. I mean, the transparency does exist where it should ( between the blue color blocks ). The image is just trimmed to get rid of that extra blank space that you don't normally need.

It does kinda look like you are trying to export all contents within the document, in which case I might recommend `Save For Web...` like @Nomadme answered.

---

**When you are using the Assets Generator, you can use `Layer mask` to define bounds for the image.**

Like this:

[image]

Comment: This did it. Total amateur here and i've never used masks before.

Comment: Is this supposed to work with CC 2014 or later as well?  No matter what I try, when I try this, the mask is still only applied to the bounds of the group, not the image.  Note that in my case this is all being done within a smart object, so when I save it back to the container, the container seems to have lost the masked size of the object.

Comment: @PKCLsoft I haven't used the asset generator actively ( it might have changed, but it doesn't seem like it ) and I'm not entirely clear on what you're saying, but I would hazard a guess that you are doing something wrong. Any chance you could prepare an example document and explain how you want the image to be exported?

Comment: @joonas sure, I've got such a document ready, though I don't seem to be able to add it to a comment here, so I may have to ask a new question.

Comment: @PKCLsoft you can't add psd files to questions either. You can make a link in the comments by wrapping it like this, expect without the space after the first square bracket: [ my link](http://). So you can add a link to like dropbox or something.

Comment: [update]  OK solved my problem though the technique is as far from intuitive as I could think.  This solution was actually provided to me offline.

Apparently I had to cmd-click on the thumbnail before creating the layer mask, otherwise the mask was being created against the whole image which is useless if you have 30 button in a single document (as I do).

Comment: Awesome, the layer mask trick was exactly what I needed. This is not documented in the official docs (https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would do just Save for Web and choose PNG-24 and make sure check the Transparency option.

In order to save the margin on the right, make sure you leave extra pixel on the canvas exactly how much margin you want to have.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think OP was hoping for an answer to do with the auto asset generator, not the save-for-web dialog.

Answer (score -1):

I found in the properties tab you can switch "Artboard background" to transparent and it works.  Default is set to white.

[image]